# Replacing positional embedding with pre-calculated results in BERT leads to poor prediction result

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to use `BERT` for a `NER` task. To achieve better prediction results, I'm trying to replace the positional embedding in the `embedding_postprocessor()` function with some pre-calculated results, based on the principle of `sinusoidal embedding`, as presented in paper `"Attention is all you need"`.

Although after about `20 hours training`, the model seems achieving good convergence (loss drops to about 10^-2 or 10^-3), the tested results were pretty bad, with the accuracy rate around 20%-30%.

Has anyone tried to replace the `positional embedding` of `BERT` with other implementation methods? Will the idea of using `sinusoidal embedding` work in `BERT`? or we could only stick to the learned `positional embedding` in `BERT`?

Comment: I haven't worked with BERT before, but you say your loss drops really low. What does your validation loss look like? Do you see signs of over fitting?

Comment: Don't think it's over fitting. Have tested with the original BERT model with learned positional embedding, and the results are 70-80% accuracy with the same dataset. However, the accuracy dropped drastically after replacing the learned positional embedding with the sinusoidal embedding. Can't figure out the reason since in the paper "Attention is all you need", the authors stated that "We also experimented with using learned positional embeddings [9] instead, and found that the two versions produced nearly identical results".